# MFC Button ToolTip not showing after button click

Tags: mfc, windows-xp, tooltip, windows-messages

I am using MFC CToolTipCtrl for creating tooltip for a button. Now I have problem when I run the application in Windows XP.When I place mouse over the button,tooltip will popup but after clicking the button no tooltip is shown.In windows 7 there is no such problem. I've used the following code to create tooltip

```
pToolTip->Create(this);

TOOLINFO ToolInfo;
ToolInfo.cbSize     = sizeof(TOOLINFO);
ToolInfo.lpszText   = const_cast<LPTSTR>(szToolTipText);
ToolInfo.hinst      = AfxGetInstanceHandle();
ToolInfo.hwnd       = pButton->m_hWnd;
ToolInfo.uFlags     = TTF_SUBCLASS | TTF_IDISHWND;
ToolInfo.uId        = (UINT)pButton->m_hWnd;

pToolTip->SendMessage(TTM_ADDTOOL, 0, (LPARAM) &ToolInfo);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try call relayevent in the `preTanslateMessage` function.

From MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/x61cthdf(v=vs.80).aspx

In order for the tool tip control to be notified of important messages, such as WM_LBUTTONXXX messages, you must relay the messages to your tool tip control. The best method for this relay is to make a call to CToolTipCtrl::RelayEvent, in the PreTranslateMessage function of the owner window.

The following example illustrates one possible method (assuming the tool tip control is called m_ToolTip):

```
if(pMsg->message== WM_LBUTTONDOWN ||
        pMsg->message== WM_LBUTTONUP ||
        pMsg->message== WM_MOUSEMOVE)
m_ToolTip.RelayEvent(pMsg);

return CMyView::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
```

If you're using VS2010 above, you can just use CMFCButton, it has a method to set the tooltip, makes life much easier.